# change date of NSDate while keeping the time same

Tags: ios, iphone

I get current time or time stamp of some image. I have to change only date while the time should not be changed. For example I use [NSdate date] to get current date and time and store in an NSdate object that is "2014-01-10 09:58:47 +0000". Now change only the date part, keeping the time same as it is "2013-11-09 09:58:47 +0000" 
How can I achieve that?

Comment: What about time zone changes?

Comment: u can save that date and time into a string then break that string after that u can change whatever u want and on next step u can merge both date and time and u can show after that

Comment: no, time zone change will affect the time. Just change the date. Like replacing substring of a string

Comment: its pretty simple. this will help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4J59r6EWOI

Comment: yeah I had that idea. But this does not look so good. can date NSDateFormatter be used to change the date only??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the date into it's date components (which includes the time part), change the date part of the components to be for the new day, and create a new date based on these components.

`dateByAddingDateComponents` is also another way to do it.

It's all described in the [Calendrical Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) documentation.